# Comment Notification Feed Not Working

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, notifications

Is anyone else noticing today that the comment notification feed isn't working for them? I'm not getting any notifications of responses to comments I've made even though I know they're being posted. I'm using Chrome Ver 38.0.2125.111 m on Win 8.1.

Comment: Appears the issue has been fixed with the exception of items missing in my feed history from while the feed was down. Comments are at least showing up again.